# Getting Couldn't find MIME boundary

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, mime-types, mime

I am calling my multipart method using Postman. Its giving me error by saying

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: 
Couldn't find MIME boundary: ------WebKitFormBoundary1wc6YPPaUQ5m6L5g
```

My Service class is:

```
@POST
    @Path("/saveDocumentDetails")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
    public Response saveDocumentDetails(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream icomingFile,@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails) throws JcmsSystemException, JcmsDataException, ParseException, ApplicationException, IOException;
```

My ServiceImpl method is :-

```
public Response saveDocumentDetails(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream icomingFile,
                @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails) throws JcmsSystemException, JcmsDataException, ParseException, ApplicationException, IOException {
            System.out.println("in Save Documents Details---------");
            try{


            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Below is the sceen shot for postman request.

[image: Screenshot]

Not using any content type.
I am using CXF 2.7.10  jar.

Can anybody help me to figure this out where i am doing wrong

Comment: There is no screenshot. How does the raw request look like?

Comment: Thanks for edit @andih, I added the image but its look like it didn't attached properly let me add again.

Comment: @andih : http://imgur.com/a/3OevI this is the link for image

Comment: Cxf is complaining about a missing mime boundary. You have to figure out what your rest service actually receives (raw data). In order to do so you can have a look at the raw tab of the postman request. You then may add this raw request data to this post (without the image data - use a placeholder for the image data)  so that someone can have a look at it or you check yourself if it contains a mime boundary "------WebKitFormBoundary1wc6YPPaUQ5m6L5g" see [7.2.1 Multipart: The common syntax](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)

Comment: "In order to do so you can have a look at the raw tab of the postman request. You then may add this raw request data to this post (without the image data - use a placeholder for the image data) "

Can you explain more on above which you mention in comment. I am new to Postman and web services.

Comment: See the Postman Blog [Inspecting Postman Requests](http://blog.getpostman.com/2015/06/13/debugging-postman-requests/) for details how to see what's going on. You may also use the postman console [The Postman Console](http://blog.getpostman.com/2016/08/26/the-postman-console/) to see the request / response.